# How make a better markdown for developer blog

Tags: python, markdown, code-formatting

I'm rebuilding my blog at http://www.elmalabarista.com/blog/. I have use in my previous version markdown and now I remember why I have almost zero code samples. Doing code samples in markdown is very fragile.

I try to put some python there I can't make markdown mark it as code!. The main culprit? The syntax is markdown for code is out spaces. Despite the fact I use wmd as the editor (how that work here in SO is a mistery for me), it never be able to move rigth the text so never get as code. this is the problem:

I put something simple:

```
:::python
def hello():
   pass
```

But the problem is that something I have:

:::python
   def hello():
     pass

or

:::python
  def hello():
     pass

(yes bot was formatted but you see? not work). Any mistake -using tabs, too much, too litle spaces) is punished heavily. And if the code is long, the chance of a problem increase too.

So, exist any way to simply do:

### My article

1. My list entry one
2. My list entry two

:::python
def x (a, b):
   return a * b

and get converted rigth and never bother about this small thing again???

By the way, I'm using pygments & python markdown.

Answer (score 3):

Consider using [reStructuredText](http://docutils.sourceforge.net/rst.html) -- it's the standard lightweight markup for Python, and is often used for docstrings and embedded documentation. It's quite easy, but also powerful -- if I remember correctly, the core Python libraries and Django both use it.

Comment: Yes, in combination with sphinx (http://sphinx.pocoo.org/) it's a great tool.  If I remember correctly Doug Hellmann (http://www.doughellmann.com/PyMOTW/) mentioned he uses rest/sphinx for the Python module of the week blog.

Comment: reST seconded. The docutils library which implements it in Python is very friendly and simple to understand and extend

Comment: But have the same problem. I follow http://www.codekoala.com/blog/2008/syntax-highlighting-rest-pygments-and-django/ and still is necesary to precisely indent each line of code to the formating works. So, no candy.

Comment: I don't understand. The problem is that the syntax for code blocks uses indentation? If so, the best solution is to add a macro to your editor to indent by four spaces. Then you just paste the code listing, select it, indent, and it'll work.

Comment: Except when not work!

I try to paste 6 times before have it *totally* rigth. Is easy in few lines but is not that reliable for long code...

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [google-code-prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/), which works pretty well.

**[Usage](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)**:

Put code snippets in <pre class="prettyprint">...</pre> or <code class="prettyprint">...</code> and it will automatically be pretty printed.

Comment: Ok, but I format the code with markdown. I if I use this kind f JS solutions I will need to manually out the html tags, defeating the use of a text-only content.

Comment: you can put standard html tags in markdown and markdown won't mess with them... so why not <code> and </code>?

Answer (score 1):

You need to indent code more than 4 spaces (btw have you noticed on SO if you add 4 spaces it gets recognized as code), this is 4 space indented:

```
:::python
def hello():
    pass
```